# i am having trouble inserting data in table in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
private void btn_view_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_emp", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        dgv_emptable.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        con.Close();
}

private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into tbl_emp(emp_id,emp_name,emp_surname,designation_id,dept_id) Values(" + txt_id.Text + " , '" + txt_name.Text + "','" + txt_phone.Text + "'," + cmb_desigid.SelectedValue + ",'" + cmb_deptid.SelectedValue.ToString() +"')"; 
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
        con.Close();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_designation", con);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    cmb_desigid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    cmb_desigid.DisplayMember = "designation_type";
    cmb_desigid.ValueMember = "designation_id";

    con.Close();

    con.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_dept",con);

    DataSet dm = new DataSet();
    db.Fill(dm);

    cmb_deptid.DataSource = dm.Tables[0];
    cmb_deptid.DisplayMember = "dept_name";
    cmb_deptid.ValueMember = "dept_id";

    con.Close();
}
```

I have bound my database and I am writing an insert query to insert data in table but I get the same error at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`

> no given parameters are given for required parameters.

I have checked thoroughly but can't seem to find the error

I have used textbox for emp_id,emmp_name,emp_surname,and two combo boxes for designation_id and dept_id.
the dept_id and designation_id are foreign key in tbl_emp. and i also have used the combo box property.So can anyone please tell what the error is and also if i have writtern the combo box code properly...

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I second @marc_s's comment but shouldn't cmb_desigid.SelectedValue be enclosed in quotes?

Comment: i am sorry but i am not able to understand what am i supposed to do

Comment: @vc74 i have enclosed one comb box in  in double quotes as its number and the other combo box in single as well as double quotes as its a string value

Comment: there is an @ in the user input

Comment: @MohamedElrashid Indeed, or a colon, or something else depending on the dbms which is unknown

Comment: @ksg Start a debugging session, break after `cmd.CommandText = ...` and inspect the SQL code

Comment: What actual **database system** are you connecting to??

Comment: @marc_s i am using msaccess for db

Comment: Do as VC 74 suggests and copy the CommandText and paste into SQL view of a new query in Access. Try to execute this query and see what errors you get.

Comment: What Data type is the SelectedValue of cmb_desig_id?

Comment: My suspicion is that you need cmb_desig_id.SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: @jonathan the datatype of cmb_design_id is in access short text and i did try writing cmb_design_id.selectedvalue.tostring() but even then it showed the same error

Comment: You could make your life a lot easier by adding a DataSet to your visual studio project, adding your access db into the Server Explorer window, then selectively dropping tables out of server explorer into the dataset. Visual studio will write all the code you've written in your question, for you.. it will also get it right and do a much better job than you or I could do in the same amount of time (it will write in about 3 seconds a huge block of sensible, parameterized code that it would take a human all day to write). Don't waste your life writing a poor version of what VS can do for you

Comment: @ksg: Q: Have you resolved the problem?  Q: Have you considered re-implementing your code per Caius Jard's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751018/421195) below>

Answer (score 1):

You need to get in the habit of using "parameterized queries" - those won't just protect your code from the #1 vulnerability out there - SQL injection - they'll also solve a lot of thorny issues with adding quotes etc. to string values.

Try this code:

```
private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // define the insert query - OleDB uses unnamed, positional parameters 
    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp (emp_id, emp_name, emp_surname, designation_id, dept_id) " + 
                         "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    // create command 
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertQuery, con);

    // define parameters - in the proper order! - and set their values
    // The "names" like "@emp_id" that I'm using here are just to make it easier for you to grasp which parameter
    // corresponds to which columns being inserted - you could also name them "p1", "p2" etc. - not very intuitive, though ...
    // Check the *assumptions* I made for the datatypes - not sure if those are
    // really what you have - adapt as needed
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_id", OleDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text);
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_name", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txt_name.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_surname", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txt_phone.Text 
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@designation_id", OleDbType.Int).Value = cmb_desigid.SelectedValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dept_id", OleDbType.Int).Value = cmb_deptid.SelectedValue;
    
    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();    
    
    MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
}
```

As a general side note: if you're only ever interested in a single `DataTable` being returned from a query - I'd strongly recommend using this code (instead of what you have now):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_designation", con);

    // define and use a "DataTable" - not a "DataSet" (which is overkill for just a single table of data)
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    cmb_desigid.DataSource = dt;
    cmb_desigid.DisplayMember = "designation_type";
    cmb_desigid.ValueMember = "designation_id";

    con.Close();
```

Comment: You don't need to open and close a connection if you're using a data adapter; it knows how to do it itself

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in the comments that you can get VS to do all this for you, in less time, and more securely/reliably than a human could do in a day. Writing db access code is boring and annoying, here's how you hand it off:

- add a new dataset to the project, just like you would add a form or class or any other thing. Call it something sensible, not dataset1
- open the server explorer window, and add a connection to your access db
- drag the db into the dataset. Thoroughly read the long message box that pops up. No one reads this, and they should read it. It solves a lot of confusion later on when the build process is overwriting the database the exe is saving in, and it looks like your app never saves any data. Click yes
- drag some tables out of the server explorer and into the dataset. Not the appearance of a datatabke with all the same columns as your db table and a tableadapter. This thing is NOT your database table, it is a strongly typed client side datatable which is a better version of what you're doing in your code above with weakly typed datasets and datatables. A tableadapter is a better version of a dataadapter designed to work with the better datatable it is visually attached to
- switch to the forms designed
- open the data sources window from the view menu, other windows submenu
- drag one of the nodes out of data sources and onto the form

Many things appear, a data grid view, binding source, navigator, dataset, tableadapter, manager. Don't delete stuff until you understand how it all works because it will teach you a lot. Run the program

This app will work, load data, save data and you didn't so far write any code at all. VS wrote all the code for you and you can read it if you want, it's there in the .Designer.cs files on disk

Run the app, add some rows, change stuff, click save, close the app. Don't run the app again yet, but instead go into the bin/debug folder and open that db on there, in access. See your data you added/changed

Now close access and build the project again, now open the same bin/debug db in access.. see the data has gone? The build process copied the blank db from the project over the top of the db the exe altered when it ran. Make sure you grok what is happening here every time you build or you'll be very confused as to why your app "isn't saving" (it is, but the changes are being wiped by the build process)

---

Some other things you need to know about tableadapters:

- they can have more than one select command- just right click them in the dataset designer and add another query. Use parameters, like `SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = @id` and give the command a sensible name like FillById. The tableadapter will gain a method `myTabkeAdapter.FillById(someDatatableHere, 1234)` to fill that datatable with row ID 1234
- they have an Update method that takes a datatable. This is NOT JUST for running update queries. Update scans the whole passed on datatable looking for rows that need to be inserted updated or deleted and executes the relevant sql. When you change a datatable row, the change is tracked by the RowState property. If the rowstate is Added, and insert will be run by the table adapter, to insert the row. If the rowstate is Modified, an Update will be run. If the rowstate is deleted, a delete will be run. Microsoft should have called Update something else, like Save, because it causes confusion often